# Trying to use yaml.load in python fails

Tags: python-2.7, yaml, pyyaml

I'm trying to understand the use of `yaml.load()` but even running this simple code won't work for me:

```
import yaml
document = """
  a: 1
  b:
    c: 3
    d: 4
"""
print yaml.dump(yaml.load(document), default_flow_style=False)
```

When I execute this script is gives the following error - `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dump'`

This code was taken from the PyYAML documentation (http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation).

What am I missing here? How can I learn how to work with YAML in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You called your example `yaml.py` and as such your test program is imported with the `import yaml` statement, and it doesn't have a `dump` routine.
Just rename your `yaml.py` to something like `test_yaml.py`.

You should also use:

```
import sys

yaml.dump(yaml.load(document, sys.stdout, default_flow_style=False)
```

as not providing a stream as the second parameter to `dump()` causes the output to first be written to a `StringIO()` object, then to be retrieved by `.getvalue()` on that object, and then written out to `sys.stdout`. It is faster to do the latter directly.